# Google Analytics _setCampaignTrack is ignored

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have an unfortunate situation where I need to track pageviews and events for multiple analytics accounts on the same page (a regional GA account and a master GA account). We set this up as follows:

```
_gaq.push(
    // regional
    ['reg._setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-n'],
    ['reg._setDomainName', xxxx.xxxxxx.com],
    ['reg._setAllowLinker', true],
    ['reg._setCampaignTrack', true],
    // master
    ['mst._setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-n'],
    ['mst._setDomainName', xxxx.xxxxxx.com],
    ['mst._setAllowLinker', true],
    ['mst._setCampaignTrack', false]
);
```

followed by subsequent calls:

```
_gaq.push(['mst._trackPageview',<title>]);
_gaq.push(['reg._trackPageview',<title>]);
```

The regional account includes campaign utm properties in the URL created by the URL builder, and we do not wish to forward these campaigns to the master account, so we set _setCampaignTrack to false for the tracker with the mst. prefix.

Strangely, in ga-debug we see the reverse -- campaign data being sent to the master but not the regional.

How can I correct or debug this without setting up filtering inside GA on the master account itself? Is there something obviously wrong with the initial _gaq.push call?

Answer (score 0):

Try with normaly GA install (no cross domain), no setdomainname, just two fresh ananlytics code, it's will not exactly solve your problem but will give you an idea to fix.